# Function having 2 array as input parameter and 2 as output?

Tags: c#, arrays

Can I create a function C# which has 2 arrays as input parameter and 2 as output?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I've edited your question, see why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void YourFunc(Int32[] input1, Int32[] input2, out Int32[] output1, out Int32[] output2)
{
   output1 = new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3 };
   output2 = new Int32[] { 4, 5, 6 };
}

…

YourFunc(i1, i2, out o1, out o2);
```

Answer (score 1):

A method can only have one return value; however, you can use `out` parameters to return multiple results.

```
void MyFunction(int[] input1, int[] input2, out int[] output1, out int[] output2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Tuple :

```
public Tuple<Object[], Object[]> FunctionName(Object[] array1, Object[] array2)
{
    //Your code

    return new Tuple<Object[],Object[]>({},{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 2 arrays as parameters to a function, but the function can return a single thing. So you could create an object with the two arrays you need to return, and return that object.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can, buddy!

```
public ArrayGroup MyFunction(myType[] firstArg, myType[] secondArg) {
    ArrayGroup result = new ArrayGroup();
    /*Do things which fill result.ArrayOne and result.ArrayTwo */
    return ArrayGroup;
}

class ArrayGroup {
    myType[] ArrayOne { get; set;}
    myType[] ArrayTwo { get; set;}
}
```

Fill in myType with whatever types you want the arrays to be! Like `string` or `int` or a complex type!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, start with a container for the response:

```
public class Response
{
    public string[] One{get;set;}
    public string[] Two{get;set;}
}
```

And your method might look like

```
public Response DoSomething(string[] inputOne, string[] inputTwo)
{
      // do some thing interesting 

      return new Respponse
      {
            One = new string[]{"Hello","World"},
            Two = new string[]{"Goodbye","Cruel","World"},
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option one: Create a type holding the result:

```
SomeResult MyFunction(T[] arr1, T[] arr2) 
{
   // ..
   return new SomeResult(r1, r2);
}

class SomeResult
{
   public SomeResult(T[] a, T[] b) { /* .. */ }

   // Rest of implementation...
}
```

Option two: Return a tuple:

```
Tuple<T[], T[]> MyFunction(T[] arr1, T[] arr2) { }
```

Option three: Use out parameters (don't do this):

```
void MyFunction(T1[] arr1, T[] arr2, out T[] result1, out T[] result2) { }
```

I prefer option one, and recommend against using out parameters. If the two arguments are of the *same type but not interchangeable* I'd recommend also creating a type for the argument to make it a single argument function with a single result.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this!

You need to pass two output arrays as a reference to the function.

Here is the code example.

**Function**

```
private bool ArrayImp(string[] pArray1, string[] pArray2, ref string[] oArray1, ref string oArray2)
{
    //Do your work here
    //Here oArray1 and oArray2 are passed by reference so you can directly fill them
    // and get back as a output.
}
```

**Function Call**

```
string[] iArray1 = null;
string[] iArray2 = null;
string[] oArray1 = null;
string[] oArray2 = null;

ArrayImp(iArray1, iArray2, oArray1, oArray2);
```

Here you need to pass iArray1 and iArray2 as input array and you will get oArray1 and oArray2 as output.

Cheeerss!! Happy Coding!!